# How to join values in 2 columns with 1 column? - SQL

Tags: sql, join, amazon-redshift

Suppose I have 2 tables like:

```
table_a 
student teacher
A       Z
B       Z
C       Z
    
    
table_b 
id  person
1   A
2   B
3   C
4   Z
```

I'm looking for an output of:

```
table_c 
student_id  teacher_id
1           4
2           4
3           4
```

I've been trying to solve this for a while, but can't figure out a simple method and believe I'm overthinking this. I'm confused how it's possible to join values in `student` and `teacher` with the `person` to get my output. I usually attach code that I've tried to my posts but am honestly drawing blanks here.

Comment: After I get all the pairings, I want to keep basically everything in my `id_mappings` output. So just the `student_id` and `teacher_id` columns

Comment: A [mre] includes cut & paste & runnable code & example input; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.) PS Clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use two correlated-subqueries to make it.

```
SELECT (SELECT b.id  FROM table_b b WHERE b.person = a.student LIMIT 1) student_id,
       (SELECT b.id  FROM table_b b WHERE b.person = a.teacher LIMIT 1) teacher_id
FROM table_a  a
```